# jQuery exception if element doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working with jQuery and I need to get anytime and anywere exception (with any operation), if I attach some event or try to perform some action with elements (got from selector) that don't exist.
Is there some internal "strict" mode in jQuery for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't.

However, you could make a simple plugin for it:

```
$.fn.checkEmpty = function() {
    if (!this.length)
        throw new Error("No elements matched by " + this.selector);
    return this;
};

$('...').checkEmpty().bind(...);
```

Alternatively:

```
function $s() { return $.apply(this, arguments).checkEmpty(); }

$s('...').bind(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this post for ways to handle an "exists"

[Exists in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Right, the real answer is "no" for strict mode, there are no modes.  This just points out some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the beauty of jQuery.

You could create a wrapper function

```
function myjQuery() {
  var res = $.apply(this, arguments);

  if (!res.size()) {
    throw new Error("No elements matched :(");
  };

  return res;
};

myjQuery('input').each();
```

This won't mask empty sets returned by using `find()` or `filter()` and the like, but humm...

Comment: How come you see this as ‘beauty’?